# No clue what happening with this dimmer connection

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

Do you know what is happening in this electric box?

A red, white, and blue wire come in, and a red and white go to the receptacle.

The red and white complete a circuit and the blue and white complete a circuit, i.e. i light up a nightlight with these.

The white in is hard wired to the white out.

The blue in is connected to the black input on the dimmer switch.

The red, and this is what is weird, is split off, connecting to the red out, and connecting to the red wire into the dimmer.

Anyone know what's going on here?
[image]

Comment: What happened to the receptacle you mentioned?

Comment: I disconnected the dimmer so i can only say that a light fixture was plugged into the receptacle and it was controlled by the dimmer.

Comment: You can't put a dimmer on a receptacle, sorry. Given that it's a 2-gang box, I suggest fitting a 2-gang mud ring, and setting a plain switch and dimmer next to each other.  Have the plain switch operate the outlet, and the dimmer operate the light (possibly when the plain switch is on).

Comment: Thanks for all your input.  I replaced the dimmer with a basic switch.  Good enough for my needs.I've put a few smart bulbs around my home, and that allowed for color changes, dimming, and timing.  That'll take care of special needs of it comes up in this room.

Answer (score 1):

**Neutral** on White, continuing to elsewhere.

<strike>**Unswitched Hot** on Red, continuing to elsewhere.</strike>

<strike>**Switched Hot** on Blue, going to whatever fixture the dimmer controls.</strike>

Following *new information* that the receptacle on red/white is controlled by the dimmer:

**Switched Hot** on Red, going to at least two locations. Presumably one is the receptacle?

**Unswitched Hot** on Blue, going to the dimmer..

Comment: Thanks.  I need to wrap my head around this.  It seems the red and white are headed for the receptacle.  When i touch those two wires to a nightlight, nothing. So i don't get how the blue can control the receptacle.  I can get into the attic and crawl to verify the direction of the conduit.

Comment: More details get better results. When you say wires lead to a receptacle, and you don't mention that the receptacle is controlled by a switch/dimmer, Occam's razor cuts towards that being the unswitched hot. Tell me that the receptacle is controlled by the dimmer and that changes (and that outlet is dangerous for things that are not dimmable lamps. - Might even be a code violation now.)

Comment: i know that there is a lamp plugged into a wall socket and it controlled by the dimmer.  This a new home for me.  I can replace the dimmer with a switch to be safe.

Comment: There may be another outlet or fixture controlled by the dimmer - that's implied by the red wire running back up where the blue came from.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  I may have to reconnect it and see if there are multiple outlets controlled by the dimmer.  What is confusing is i can light up a nightlight by connecting the red and white, and the blue and white form the upper conduit.

Comment: Well, if you disconnected the wires to make that check, that gets into "this does not appear to make sense, if the wiring is as you show" since then the dimmer should have no effect on the receptacle that's connected to red and white - if the red and white connected to the receptacle are the ones leaving this box from the bottom, anyway.

Comment: I will reconnect tomorrow and find out what's being controlled.  I have made assumptions that seem to be wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a 3-way dimmer with a switch.

The incoming white neutral passes through. That is typical and good.

The incoming blue is hot coming in. That is typical and good.

The outgoing reds are output from the dimmer which goes to two different places. Where they go? Disconnect one at a time and find out. The output should not go to an outlet because many things that plug into an outlet do not want a dimmer and vice versa (dimmer will not appreciate a heavy draw). This does not mean that the red wire does not feed an outlet.

The unused red from the dimmer is for a three way switch application. The lack of its use is expected in a two-way application.

The green from the dimmer is ground. It should be attached to the metal box with a green screw. The head of a green electrical screw is made to hold a wire down onto a flat surface (the box).

Comment: You're mostly right, although the main reason you don't want to connect a dimmer to a receptacle is because some loads (motors, older electronics) have a rather dim view of being dimmed